# Remove entry and Insert Entry in Linked Lists functions operating on the wrong entries

Tags: c, struct, linked-list

Good afternoon. I'm learning the C language from a book called Programming in C Third Edition by Stephen G. Kochan. I wrote some code that is supposed to insert and remove certain entries from a list, which it does, the problem is, it does not remove the right entry, and it does not quite insert the entry in the right spot. The code is below. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
//Insert and Remove entry functions using doubly linked lists
#include <stdio.h>

struct Entry
{
    int Value;
    struct Entry *Previous;
    struct Entry *Next;
};


int main()
{
    void InsertEntry (struct Entry *InsertPosition, struct Entry EntryToInsert);
    void RemoveEntry (struct Entry *EntryToRemove);
    struct Entry N1, N2, N3, N4, N5, Insert, *Start = &N1;

//set initial values
    N1.Value = 10;
    N2.Value = 20;
    N3.Value = 20;
    N4.Value = 30;
    N5.Value = 40;
    Insert.Value = 35;

//link the list

    N1.Next = &N2;
    N2.Next = &N3;
    N3.Next = &N4;
    N4.Next = &N5;
    N5.Next = (struct Entry *) 0;
//Link again

    N1.Previous = &N1;
    N2.Previous = &N1;
    N3.Previous = &N2;
    N4.Previous = &N3;
    N5.Previous = &N4;

    InsertEntry(&N4, Insert);
    RemoveEntry(&N2);

//Display the Lists
    while (Start->Next != (struct Entry *) 0)
    {
        printf("Previous: %i, Current: %i, Next: %i\n",         Start->Previous->Value, Start->Value, Start->Next->Value);
        Start = Start->Next;
    }

    return 0;
}

void InsertEntry (struct Entry *InsertPosition, struct Entry EntryToInsert)
{

    EntryToInsert.Previous = InsertPosition->Previous;
    EntryToInsert.Next = InsertPosition;
    InsertPosition->Previous->Next = &EntryToInsert;

}

void RemoveEntry (struct Entry *EntryToRemove)
{
    EntryToRemove->Previous->Next = EntryToRemove->Next;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several problems in the code.

Move the declarations for InsertEntry and RemoveEntry to before the main().

When initializing Previous fields, head of the list needs to have Previous = NULL.

When printing out list, need to avoid printing out Previous->Value and Next->Value for head and tail of list, respectively.

In InsertEntry() function, code is passing EntryToInsert struct by value which inserts a copy into the list. I am guessing you intended to pass by pointer which would insert the original stucture into the list.

In InsertEntry() function, need to also set InsertPosition->Next->Previous.

In InsertEntry() function before setting InsertPosition->Previous->Next and InsertPosition->Next->Previous, need to check that you are not at head and tail of list, respectively.

In RemoveEntry() function, need to also set EntryToRemove->Next->Previous.

In RemoveEntry() function before setting EntryToRemove->Previous->Next and EntryToRemove->Next->Previous, need to check that you are not at head and tail of list, respectively.

In RemoveEntry() function, need to also set EntryToRemove->Previous = NULL and EntryToRemove->Next = NULL.

I would suggest you attempt to fix each of the above mentioned issues on your own. If you run into problems fixing a given issue, I have included the complete code with my suggested fixes for you to look at.

```
struct Entry
{
    int Value;
    struct Entry *Previous;
    struct Entry *Next;
};

void InsertEntry(struct Entry *InsertPosition, struct Entry *EntryToInsert);
void RemoveEntry(struct Entry *EntryToRemove);

int main()
{
    struct Entry N1, N2, N3, N4, N5, Insert, *Start = &N1;

    //set initial values
    N1.Value = 10;
    N2.Value = 20;
    N3.Value = 20;
    N4.Value = 30;
    N5.Value = 40;
    Insert.Value = 35;

    //link the list

    N1.Next = &N2;
    N2.Next = &N3;
    N3.Next = &N4;
    N4.Next = &N5;
    N5.Next = NULL;
    //Link again

    N1.Previous = NULL;
    N2.Previous = &N1;
    N3.Previous = &N2;
    N4.Previous = &N3;
    N5.Previous = &N4;

    InsertEntry(&N4, &Insert);
    RemoveEntry(&N2);

    //Display the Lists
    while (Start != (struct Entry *) 0)
    {
        printf("Previous: ");
        if (Start->Previous != NULL)
        {
            printf("%i", Start->Previous->Value);
        }
        else
        {
            printf("NULL");
        }
        printf(", Current: %i, Next: ", Start->Value);
        if (Start->Next != NULL)
        {
            printf("%i", Start->Next->Value);
        }
        else
        {
            printf("NULL");
        }
        printf("\n");
        Start = Start->Next;
    }

    return 0;
}

void InsertEntry(struct Entry *InsertPosition, struct Entry *EntryToInsert)
{
    EntryToInsert->Previous = InsertPosition->Previous;
    EntryToInsert->Next = InsertPosition;
    if (InsertPosition->Previous != NULL)
    {
        InsertPosition->Previous->Next = EntryToInsert;
    }
    InsertPosition->Previous = EntryToInsert;

}

void RemoveEntry(struct Entry *EntryToRemove)
{
    if (EntryToRemove->Previous != NULL)
    {
        EntryToRemove->Previous->Next = EntryToRemove->Next;
    }
    if (EntryToRemove->Next != NULL)
    {
        EntryToRemove->Next->Previous = EntryToRemove->Previous;
    }
    EntryToRemove->Previous = NULL;
    EntryToRemove->Next = NULL;
}
```

Comment: :Thanks for your help. Now I really understand what I'm doing wrong. P.S - I haven't seen your code. I will implement it on my own, and report back if I have problems. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of problems with your `InsertEntry` function.

First, you need to pass in pointers to *both* the `InsertPosition` and the `EntryToInsert`.  The reason for this is because in C, everything is *pass by value*.  That means when you pass a value into a function, that function will see a *copy* of that value, not the original value.  Once that function completes - the copy is gone forever.  So if you want to modify something inside a function, and have that modification be visible once the function completes, you have to pass a pointer to that something. A pointer in C points to a location in memory - so even if the function gets a copy of that pointer, the location it points to is the same.

This means that the first step is defining the function as:

```
void InsertEntry (struct Entry *InsertPosition*, struct Entry *EntryToInsert)
```

Second, the order in which you insert `EntryToInsert` is wrong for what you want to accomplish - you want to insert this value *after* `InsertPosition`, not before it.  Here's the corrected function with comments:

```
void InsertEntry (struct Entry *InsertPosition, struct Entry *EntryToInsert)
{
    //Goal is to insert EntryToInsert *before* InsertPosition
    //  so that it will look like:
    //  ??? --> EntryToInsert --> InsertPosition
    //Step 1: ??? <-- EntryToInsert
    EntryToInsert->Prev = InsertPosition->Prev;
    //Step 2: EntryToInsert --> InsertPosition
    EntryToInsert->Next = InsertPosition;
    //Step 3: ??? --> EntryToInsert
    EntryToInsert->Prev->Next = EntryToInsert;
    //Step 4: EntryToInsert <-- InsertPosition
    InsertPosition->Prev = EntryToInsert;
}
```

Finally - the function declarations that you currently have inside of the `main` function usually go outside (before) the function.

Fixing this should fix any problems you have with your `RemoveEntry` function - again, I see no problems with that.

Comment: This is obviously not the right place to get help like this.... I'm trying to learn C on my own, and I don't know of anyone that I personally know that knows the language. Do you know of a forrum I could go to that's aimed at people like me that could point me in the right direction?

Comment: @DaveB. - what specifically are you looking for help with? We're happy to help you if you have a specific question about *why* something does or doesn't work, but it's not going to help you if we just write the code for you.  I was trying to give you enough of a hint my answer that you could see where the error in your code was - but I'll modify my answer to achieve what I think you're trying to accomplish and provide an explanation as to why it works.

Comment: No, I know that. I have to put effort into it myself. For the insert function, I was trying to take and shift the one linked item down, and insert the entry where it was. What ended up hapening is exactly as you described. Now, for the remove function, if you set the parameters up exactly as they are (I mean if you pass &N2 to it) it sets 20 as it's previous value instead of 10. If you pas any other value to it (&N3 ect) it works flawlessly. Can you or someone you know shed some light on this?

Comment: @DaveB.: I never meant to imply that you weren't willing to put the effort in - my apologies if that's how I came off!  Let me know if that helps and if you have any other questions :)

Comment: thanks for your help. You were wrong about one thing though thanks to my stupidity. I actually did want to insert the entry before the other one. However, the way you did it, makes sense too. The big problem I can't figure out now is, why on earth is the remove function messing up (pass &N2 to it, then pass &N3 to it. The results you get should be the exact opposite). It only messes up if you pass &N2 to it. Do you know what could be causing this? Thanks again.

Comment: @DaveB. I'm not doing a very good job of hitting all of the problems - please accept Bobby's answer instead of mine and see his response.

Comment: Actually, if you play with it, especially if you pass &N2 to the InsertEntry function, you get seriously messed up values for Previous. Can you explain to me, what I'm doing wrong? P.S The author of the book wants us to make the function insert the entry at the same position as the position passed to the function. Say, you pass &N2 to the insert entry function. That's exactly where the entry should be inserted. Thanks so much for all your help.

Comment: @DaveB. - it's because I've been missing step 4 above - but even then, you have to handle for errors.  Like I said - accept Bobby's answer instead :)

Comment: Thanks for all your help. I really understand what I'm doing better now.