# Doubly-linked-list. Code works...should it? Much less code than other solution

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list

I'm working through the exercises in the 'Pointers' chapter of 'Programming in C' by Kochan.

I have written a program that creates a doubly-linked-list. It first prints the values. It then proceeds to call a function to remove an entry. The values are printed again.

Finally, an additional function is called to ADD an entry, followed by a print again.

Right now, my code works. You can see it here:

```
#include <stdio.h>


struct entry
    {
        int value;
        struct entry *next;
        struct entry *previous;
    };

void removeEntry(struct entry *start);
void insertEntry(struct entry *addOn, struct entry *element);

int main (void)
{

    //declarations
    struct entry n1, n2, n3, addOn;
    struct entry *list_pointer = &n1;


    //creates list values and links
    n1.value = 100;
    n1.next = &n2;
    n1.previous = list_pointer;

    n2.value = 200;
    n2.next = &n3;
    n2.previous = &n1;

    n3.value = 300;
    n3.next = (struct entry *) 0;
    n3.previous = &n2;

    //prints out all list values
    while(list_pointer != (struct entry *) 0)
    {
        printf("%i\n", list_pointer->value);
        list_pointer = list_pointer->next;
    }

    printf("\n");

    //resets list_pointer back to start
    list_pointer = &n1;

    //calls function and removes n2 from list by directly linking n1 to n3
    removeEntry(&n2);

    //print out amended list
    while(list_pointer != (struct entry *) 0)
    {
        printf("%i\n", list_pointer->value);
        list_pointer = list_pointer->next;
    }

    printf("\n");

    list_pointer = &n1;
    insertEntry(&addOn, &n3);

    //print out amended list
    while(list_pointer != (struct entry *) 0)
    {
        printf("%i\n", list_pointer->value);
        list_pointer = list_pointer->next;
    }

    return 0;
}

void removeEntry(struct entry *start)
{
    start->previous->next = start->next;
}

void insertEntry(struct entry *addOn, struct entry *element)
{
    element->next = addOn;
    addOn->value = 400;
    addOn->next = (struct entry *) 0;
}
```

HOWEVER, once done, I wanted to check to see if any other solutions had been posted online, just in case I was missing anything.

Well I found a question and answer [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33713395/remove-entry-and-insert-entry-in-linked-lists-functions-operating-on-the-wrong-e) and there are considerable differences.

Ignoring the difference in the format of how the values are printed, you can see that there is considerably more code written, especially in the functions. This is my remove function again:

```
void removeEntry(struct entry *start)
{
    start->previous->next = start->next;
}
```

and this is theirs:

```
void RemoveEntry(struct Entry *EntryToRemove)
{
    if (EntryToRemove->Previous != NULL)
    {
        EntryToRemove->Previous->Next = EntryToRemove->Next;
    }
    if (EntryToRemove->Next != NULL)
    {
        EntryToRemove->Next->Previous = EntryToRemove->Previous;
    }
    EntryToRemove->Previous = NULL;
    EntryToRemove->Next = NULL;
}
```

Now I can see that there is a check for NULL, but aside from that, they are working with both `Previous` and `Next` values and have an if statement for each.

Similarly, you can see my `insert` function here:

```
void insertEntry(struct entry *addOn, struct entry *element)
{

    element->next = addOn;
    addOn->value = 400;
    addOn->next = (struct entry *) 0;
}
```

and theirs:

```
void InsertEntry(struct Entry *InsertPosition, struct Entry *EntryToInsert)
{
    EntryToInsert->Previous = InsertPosition->Previous;
    EntryToInsert->Next = InsertPosition;
    if (InsertPosition->Previous != NULL)
    {
        InsertPosition->Previous->Next = EntryToInsert;
    }
    InsertPosition->Previous = EntryToInsert;
}
```

Please keep in my mind that my code does exactly what I was trying to do, my printed output is:

```
100
200
300

100
300

100
300
400
```

Can you please attempt to explain this to me? I feel like an idiot for not being able to get my head around with this.

This is their full code:

```
#include <stdio.h>vv

struct Entry
{
    int Value;
    struct Entry *Previous;
    struct Entry *Next;
};

void InsertEntry(struct Entry *InsertPosition, struct Entry *EntryToInsert);
void RemoveEntry(struct Entry *EntryToRemove);

int main()
{
    struct Entry N1, N2, N3, N4, N5, Insert, *Start = &N1;

    //set initial values
    N1.Value = 10;
    N2.Value = 20;
    N3.Value = 20;
    N4.Value = 30;
    N5.Value = 40;
    Insert.Value = 35;

    //link the list

    N1.Next = &N2;
    N2.Next = &N3;
    N3.Next = &N4;
    N4.Next = &N5;
    N5.Next = NULL;
    //Link again

    N1.Previous = NULL;
    N2.Previous = &N1;
    N3.Previous = &N2;
    N4.Previous = &N3;
    N5.Previous = &N4;

    InsertEntry(&N4, &Insert);
    RemoveEntry(&N2);

    //Display the Lists
    while (Start != (struct Entry *) 0)
    {
        printf("Previous: ");
        if (Start->Previous != NULL)
        {
            printf("%i", Start->Previous->Value);
        }
        else
        {
            printf("NULL");
        }
        printf(", Current: %i, Next: ", Start->Value);
        if (Start->Next != NULL)
        {
            printf("%i", Start->Next->Value);
        }
        else
        {
            printf("NULL");
        }
        printf("\n");
        Start = Start->Next;
    }

    return 0;
}

void InsertEntry(struct Entry *InsertPosition, struct Entry *EntryToInsert)
{
    EntryToInsert->Previous = InsertPosition->Previous;
    EntryToInsert->Next = InsertPosition;
    if (InsertPosition->Previous != NULL)
    {
        InsertPosition->Previous->Next = EntryToInsert;
    }
    InsertPosition->Previous = EntryToInsert;

}

void RemoveEntry(struct Entry *EntryToRemove)
{
    if (EntryToRemove->Previous != NULL)
    {
        EntryToRemove->Previous->Next = EntryToRemove->Next;
    }
    if (EntryToRemove->Next != NULL)
    {
        EntryToRemove->Next->Previous = EntryToRemove->Previous;
    }
    EntryToRemove->Previous = NULL;
    EntryToRemove->Next = NULL;
}
```

Thank you for your time.

Comment: To start with you have a `*previous` member in your node but you never use it. Your code does not implement a doubly linked list ...

Comment: Already answered, but as to not being able to "weapons your head around it"--get some paper and a pencil and play computer for a bit: work through the code until you understand it. Being able to digest existing code is a pretty important skill.

Comment: What would happen if your code try to use removeEntry with n1, in that case n1->previous should point to list_pointer, but list_pointer does not have  next pointer. For a removeEntry(&n1), list_pointer should be updated to point to n2, and n2->previous should be set to null.

Comment: Same point, what about `insertEntry(addOn, n1)`?

Comment: Don't cast a null pointer constant. Use the `NULL` macro! C is not C++!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code is different because your code does not successfully implement a double linked list. For example try inserting an entry into the middle of the list then print it from the end to the start, you will find the linked code works, but yours does not.

Comment: I don't know what a node is, I haven't come across that in the book yet.

Comment: replace 'node' with 'entry' and this should make sense to you

Comment: @MattCleary I used node as another term for `entry`.

Comment: @gloopit: The code to 'remove' and entry only sorts out one of the two pointers that needs to be adjusted.  You should have your printing code print both using the `next` pointer chain and the `prev` pointer chain.  If the two outputs aren't equivalent but reversed, you've got problems.

Answer (score 2):

> Please keep in my mind that my code does exactly what I was trying to do, my printed output is:....

This is the single most **dangerous** and **naive** thing new programmers say. It tells us absolutely nothing.  Programming is not a matter of the ends justify the means.  You can push the wrong buttons on a calculator and get the right answer no?

Your test consists of traversing in a single direction through your list.  A singly linked list would have passed that test.

Did you test reverse traversal? That is after all the key difference between a singly linked list and a doubly linked one.
Did you test insertion and removal from the middle and from the front and back?

How about cycles? What happens if you add an element to the list that's already in the list?

Comment: It's not a matter of sorry; its a matter of that's the difference. Figure out how to write a test that shows why your code is wrong, and figure out how to make it right.

Comment: @MattCleary There is no point being sorry for being wrong. Least of all being sorry to some anonymous person on the Internet who figured out why you're wrong.

Comment: As the anonymous person, I agree, no apology needed; I was just trying to point something out to help you in the process of learning and figuring this stuff out for yourself.  My aim is to help you figure out how to fish and not to just give you the fish. Think like a fisherman so to speak :-)